# T-SQL Return number of rows with max value and max value itself of newly created column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Table `Employee` contains four columns:

```
employee_id, name, salary, months
```

[image]

Task: return number of rows with maximal value of `salary * months` and this maximal value, my last attempt is :

`SELECT

  months*salary FROM employee 
  WHERE salary*months = (SELECT MAX(months*salary) 
                         FROM Employee)`
adding `COUNT(months*salary)` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Employee 
WHERE salary * months = (SELECT max(salary * months) FROM Employee)
```

If you only want to know how many records then:

```
SELECT count(1),  max(salary * month) FROM Employee 
WHERE salary * months = (SELECT max(salary * months) FROM Employee)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a windowed `MAX()`:

```
Select  employee_id, name, salary, months,
        Max(months * salary) Over (Order By (Select Null)) As MaxSalary
From    Employee
```

This will return all rows and add a 5th column `MaxSalary` to the results that would have the same value for every row - the max `months * salary` in the recordset.